# ViewPager with ImageView before tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to create an activity where there's an image view and a view pager right after.  I have try some stuff, but the tabs of the viewpager always appear at the top of the screen.

In order what I would like to have:

- Action Bar
- Image view (here the M)
- Tab
- Content of the tab (Fragment)

Here's the closest I have got.

[image: a]

Here's my code. (I'm pretty sur I overkilled it, but I was trying stuff)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image_linear_layout">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="madduck.ioweyou.ProfileActivity" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a TabLayout instead of the ActionBar tabs.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html

Comment: Thanks it worked your way, I used that for [reference](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout).  Here's the [result](http://i.imgur.com/3ISVN1f.png)

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you'd need to use the [Android Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) (which is really just another View with some half-baked additions).

have a layout like this in your activity: (pseudo code)

```
<TOOLBAR>
<IMAGEVIEW>
<VIEWPAGER WITH TABS>
```

You'll want to declare your Theme/Styles to make sure your activity contains no action bar (since you will be replacing it with the Toolbar). Also some versions of Android used to crash if you tried to add a Toolbar when there was an ActionBar. Not sure if this was *fixed*.

Comment: Looks like this would have work too, but I used Raanan method with the tab layout.

Thanks